# Automate PyTest across Enviroments in VSCode

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, continuous-integration, pytest

While VSCode recognizes the Test files and runs them, I find myself having to constantly switch environments to test various Python versions. What is the best way to set up a git commit/savefile hook to run my tests in different environments?

I tried using the provided tasks to set the environment and then execute the tests using dependsOn and dependsOrder, however, this appears to revert back to the set environment at the end of each individual tasks. Chaining them using && is also prohibited. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you consider tox? https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tox](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) and [nox](https://pypi.org/project/nox/) are how most people run tests under multiple versions of Python.